# importing data on phpmyadmin to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I have a database on phpmyadmin and I would like to import some data from a csv file.

- My database is structured in the following way: there are N tables,
  each one of them has the same number of columns (M).
- In my csv file I have N rows, each row with M values. When importing the file
- I would like to add the first row to the first table, second row to the
  second table and so on.

How can I do it? I've looked online but only found how to import data to one table, not to multiple tables at the same time.
Thanks for your help

Comment: "there are N tables, each one of them has the same number of columns (M)" -- sounds like this could be a very bad design... If all of them store instances of the same entity type, it should be just one table.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way for phpMyAdmin to handle that type of complex import.

There are a number of ways you could use text-processing tools to manipulate the data in to a more usable form for import, but at that point you might as well add 20 more lines of code and handle the import directly. Using phpMyAdmin for this type of import is going to be inefficient, but what you may benefit from is splitting the file in to individual files (per-table) and using the phpMyAdmin drag-and-drop import feature to change to a table and drop the file for a quick import. It's somewhat fewer clicks than going to the Import tab, navigating to the file, and then selecting to import.